# SSIS Script task Fails when switching to 2016 Target Server using Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: ssis, json.net

Morning,

I have developed some C# code inside a script task that queries a table in a SQL server and then serializes the data to JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON. This is done VS 2019 and is targeted to SQL Server 2019 as well. Everything runs great, but when I switch it to a Targeted Version of SQL Server 2016 so I can deploy to our SSIS Server (It runs on 2016) it crashes. I have tried to create it in VS 2015 and 2017 as well and it bombs out each time I switch to 2016. I am getting a 'Exception has been thrown by target of invocation error', but setting breakpoints etc doesn't work because it doesn't even make it to the code in the script before it errors out. If I take the serialization code out and remove `Using Newtonsoft.Json` I can get it to run as well leading me to believe there is an issue with Newtonsoft.JSON, or the way it's setup.

Has anyone else ran into this issue before? I have checked my frame work and it's running .net 4.5 Framework, so it shouldn't have any issues?

Comment: nuget or gac install of Newtonsoft?

Comment: I installed using Nuget

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for leading me down the path of the GAC to install Newtonsoft billinkc. It's working great now on my machine. It's not working on the server yet, which I assume means Newtonsoft has an issue on the server which i'll defer to the DBA.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a great answer for how to get nuget to work with SSIS script tasks. I mean, it works great while you're in the VS editor but as soon as you exit out, VS cleans up the working directory which means all the packages are wiped out. The nuget bits aren't serialized into the resulting assembly. The launch of the script task process doesn't know it needs to pull the packages first so Boom goes the dynamite.